# pull from heroku gets empty git but there's an online site

Tags: git, heroku, git-clone, git-pull

Trying to retrieve old code for updating...

```
heroku git:clone -a appname
```

creates empty dir...

---

So:

```
$ git clone https://git.heroku.com/appname.git
Cloning into 'appname'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

$ git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/appname.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/appname.git (push)

$  git pull https://git.heroku.com/appname.git heroku
fatal: couldn't find remote ref heroku

git pull https://git.heroku.com/appname.git
fatal: couldn't find remote ref HEAD
```

login via heroku bash and "ls -la" i can check there is no .git folder in my app but it works online and i should have pushed it tru heroku cli as theres no other way ( i dont use public github).

It's a django app.

Also tried without understanding well an answer i found:

```
git fetch -vv --all
Fetching heroku
Fetching here
fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/heroku
error: could not fetch here

git reset --hard HEAD
```

which just resets a commit i had locally without fetching remote git

```
 git remote set-head heroku -a
error: Cannot determine remote HEAD
```

remote update silent goes on

```
$ git remote update
Fetching heroku
$
```

---

*App was in maintenance mode, which shouldnt affect but tried by enabling it and do everything again

---

edit: i'm diving into this which might or not have been the case
[heroku help for cloned empty link](https://help.heroku.com/XOBUHLKQ/why-do-i-see-a-message-you-appear-to-have-cloned-an-empty-repository-when-using-heroku-git-clone)

```
heroku git:remote -a appname
```

it does set remote but i don't have the correct name of the app template used in case it was tru button deploy, which i don't know, but i doubt was the case.
So it's not the same case as [Heroku "cloned an empty repository" message for a repository that isn't empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71958592/heroku-cloned-an-empty-repository-message-for-a-repository-that-isnt-empty)

**edit2: this solution by heroku just retrieves the original template, but not the changes that you would have developed further from it

---

It probably could only be resolved with the heroku support which im waiting answer.

Or with this hack to retrieve the files https://code-examples.net/es/q/1478abd

Comment: "i should have pushed it tru heroku cli as theres no other way ( i dont use public github)"—I missed this when marking the duplicate. Are you entirely sure you didn't deploy with GitHub? It doesn't need to be a _public_ repo to do that. If you didn't deploy via GitHub, any chance you deployed as a container?

Comment: I can't remember since its from more than 1 year ago.
But i rejected github when they announced only private repos for paying users. Which seems to have changed now. I don't have that repo on my github.
I don't think I used containers as they are still hard for me to work with. No dockerfiles on heroku bash ls.

Comment: And you don't have a copy anywhere else? [Heroku's Git repository isn't meant to be your main remote](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app): "A Heroku app’s Git repository is intended for deployment purposes only. Cloning from this repository is not officially supported as a feature and should be attempted only as a last resort. **Do not** use this repository as your app’s canonical “origin” repository. Instead, use your own Git server or a version control service such as GitHub."

Comment: That's right, i just read that. I will check backups but they would be outdated vs the heroku version... $things happen...
Actually creating a git from heroku run bash might be the solution #1 https://code-examples.net/es/q/1478abd

Comment: Did you maybe [fork it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fork-app)? Or deploy via a [Heroku Button](https://www.heroku.com/elements/buttons)? The only time Heroku's Git repository will contain your source code is if you pushed directly to it. Though I see in question of [the other dupe I just added](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13804885/354577) that this can also occur if there's corruption on the Heroku end. Glad you've already got a support request out to them.

Comment: I dont think i forked it. But could be the case. Never with a heroku fork command but with git maybe
It probably was deployed with this with an older python version
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python#buildpack-instructions
So far so good. ty